# restricted shell (rsh) on raspbian

Tags: user

I want to run the restricted shell (rsh) on the raspberry pi as the default shell for a user, but I can't seem to find it.

my code is:

```
sudo su
adduser restricteduser
cd ~restricteduser
chmod  446 .profile 
mkdir bin
```

restricteduser's .profile file is

```
declare SHELL=/usr/bin/rsh
declare PATH=/usr/rbin:$HOME/bin:.
export PATH SHELL
```

Comment: What does I can't seem to find it mean?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a read over the [invocation section here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell), and note that `sh` on Raspbian is actually a link to `bash`, which will conform to `sh` type behavior when invoked that way.

However, because of the naming collision with "remote shell", which the latter won, `/usr/bin/rsh` is *not* what you are looking for.

I'd try `/bin/rbash` instead.